# Anaconda Keras Installation issue

Tags: python, keras, anaconda

I am trying to install keras using my conda environment. I have been instructed to install the keras with Tensorflow backend using the following command:

> install -c hesi_m keras

But the problem is it downloads some packages and then errors outs follows:

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages:
keras_applications-1 |   45 KB | ############### | 100%
keras-2.2.0          |  444 KB | ############### | 100% 
keras-preprocessing- |   43 KB | ############### | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed
```

CondaVerificationError: The package for keras-preprocessing located at /home/usama/anaconda3/pkgs/keras-preprocessing-1.0.1-py36_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib\python3.6\site-packages\Keras_Preprocessing-1.0.1-py3.6.egg-info\PKG-INFO'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for keras-preprocessing located at /home/usama/anaconda3/pkgs/keras-preprocessing-1.0.1-py36_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib\python3.6\site-packages\Keras_Preprocessing-1.0.1-py3.6.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

Remaining list of error is skipped. I have tried to clean the cache using:

> conda clean --all

But the issue is persisting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, try installing via pip:

Go into your environment where you have TensorFlow installed and run this:

```
pip install keras
```

Comment: Although this _should_ work perfectly, the performance cost of using `pip` over `conda` is significant, especially when used for deep learning. Hence, I would advice you to prefer `conda` over `pip`. Take a look at [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-installing-tensorflow-using-pip-for-performance-sake-5854f9d9eb0c) article for more details.

Comment: @AshutoshPathak he’s only referring to the updated version of MKL. You can pop install the latest version of MKL as well. Conda irks me because it requires a more verbose command to prevent it from removing or updating other packages unnecessarily.

Comment: You are correct, but this isn't just another alternative way; tensorflow from Anaconda (or compiled with specialised math libraries) performs much better on average.

Answer (score 1):

Just google the keywords

"conda install keras".

You will get the commands to install keras directly.

For example:

open your teminal and paste the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras
```

Comment: Hi, I think this will work. Type following code in your terminal 'conda update keras'

Answer (score 0):

1) Update conda

> Run the anaconda prompt as administrator

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

2) Create an environment for python new version say, 3.6

```
conda create --name py36 python=3.6
```

3) Activate the new environment

```
conda activate py36
```

4) Upgrade pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

5) Install tensorflow

```
pip install https://testpypi.python.org/packages/db/d2/876b5eedda1f81d5b5734277a155fa0894d394a7f55efa9946a818ad1190/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

If it doesn't work

> If you have problem with wheel at the environment location, or pywrap_tensorflow problem,

```
 pip install tensorflow --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

Then, try

```
pip install keras
```